# variable amount in paypal recurring

Tags: paypal, recurring-billing

I need to implement monthly subscription with variable amount with paypal recurring system. problem is that monthly subscription fee is changable by administrator.
is it posssible to change automated recurring amount in paypal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In paypal, subscribe and unsubscribe recurring methods does not have variable amount.

With Automatic Billing and Adaptive payement system it is possible.(i never done that)